# why 3 map types in scala 2.11

Tags: scala

There are 3 map types I see in scala:

```
scala.collection.Map
scala.collection.immutable.Map
scala.collection.mutable.Map
```

immutability vs mutability ones makes perfect sense and it appears the predef has a Map alias directly to immutable.Map. I do not get why there is a scala.collections.Map though.

In addition it looks like JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap only accepts a scala.collections.Map and not the immutable one?

Comment: Have you noticed that both mutable and immutable one extend scala.collections.Map?

Comment: I do now, sorry, just a very careless rushed mistake on my part, I could not figure out why IntelliJ syntax highlighter kept marking it wrong. resolved by a rebuild

Answer (score 3):

The scala doc [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) mentioned

```
A collection in package scala.collection.immutable is guaranteed to be immutable for everyone.
...
A collection in package scala.collection.mutable is known to have some operations that change the collection in place.
...
A collection in package scala.collection can be either mutable or immutable.
```

`Map` in `scala.collections.Map` is only a trait, or an interface as in java. It provides a common APIs for both immutable and mutable Map. Without specifying, scala defaults to an immutable implementation.

**Edit**

```
In addition it looks like JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap only accepts a scala.collections.Map and not the immutable one?
```

Not really. Since both `immutable.Map` and `mutable.Map` implements trait `Map`, the `mapAsJavaMap` actually doesn't care whether the concrete implementation of `map`.

This is called [subtyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping). As the wiki page illustrate, a method expecting a `Bird` doesn't care whether the instance of bird is a `duck`, a `ostrich` or a `cuckoo`.

Answer (score 2):

Both:

```
scala.collections.immutable.Map
scala.collections.mutable.Map
```

implements/extends trait:

```
scala.collections.Map
```

You can think about it as universal interface for maps.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of [scala.collection.immutable.Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map) and [scala.collection.mutable.Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map), you'll see that both of them extend the [scala.collection.Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Map) trait, which contains common operations for a map regardless of concrete implementation. However, this is only a trait so you cannot initiate it.

Hence, the [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$).mapAsJavaMap method accepts both a immutable and a mutable variant of a map.

Comment: yup looks like there was some strange artifacts in IntelliJ and sbt that wouldnt accept it at first. does now thanks!